# For loop generation in always block

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm trying to create 32 color stripes via VGA.

```
     generate
     genvar i;

     always @(posedge vga_clk) begin
         if (x_num == 10'h3FF) 
             RGB = 16'b00000_000011_00011;
     for (i = 1; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin: rgb_gen
40:      else if ((i * 20 < x_num) && (x_num < (i + 1) * 20)) begin
             RGB = RGB << i;
         end
     end

     end
     endgenerate
```

But there is an error:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at top.v(40) near text "else"; expecting "end"
```

In my mind, result have to be following:

```
always @(posedge vga_clk) begin
    if (x_num == 10'h3FF) 
        RGB = 16'b00000_000011_00011;
    else if ((0 < x_num) && (x_num < 20))
        RGB = RGB << 0;
    else if ((20 < x_num) && (x_num < 40))
        RGB = RGB << 1;
    ..................
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed a `generate` block in the middle of a procedural block of code. I think what you want is

```
integer i;

    always @(posedge vga_clk) begin
       RGB = 0;  
       if (x_num == 10'h3FF) 
             RGB = 16'b00000_000011_00011;
         else 
         for (i = 1; i < 32; i = i + 1)
            if ((i * 20 < x_num) && (x_num < (i + 1) * 20))
             RGB = RGB << i;
       end
```